# PHP redirect page works only in localhost

Tags: php, mysql, forms, redirect

I haven't found any solutions for my problem so I decided to ask. I would like to redirect my php script page after submitting a form, so I use header at the end of my codes! Interestingly, when I test it in my localhost, it works and redirects the page successfully, but, when I test it in my remote server it fails to redirect the page! and when I submit the form, it goes to the from processing script and show a blank page! I wonder if anyone can help me on this matter.

and here is my codes in the form processing script:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/db.php'); ?>


<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['subject']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['message_area']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO contact_messages (name, email, subject, message)

VALUES ( '$name', '$email', '$subject','$message')";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if($result){
header('Location: http://www.mylink/index.htm'); 
exit();
} 
else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute the form " . mysqli_error($connection);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: have you checked after enabling `error_reporting`??? you must be getting some `header already sent error`

Comment: I bet my ass there is a problem with the query. Probably you didn't set up the db properly. Enable `error_reporting()` and check again

Comment: there should not be any output (like echo.. ...) before the header(...); command.

Comment: @YUNOWORK whitespace like line breaks are output too.

Comment: change `mysqli_error($link);` to `mysqli_error($connection);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php require_once('Connections/db.php'); ?>


<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
```

Change your above code to

```
<?php require_once('Connections/db.php'); 

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
```

and also remove the last `?>` if you do not have html after that.

After that, it should work.

---

To turn on Error Reporting, place `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your php script, and you should be able to see the error.

More info about the problem you are facing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/3113793)

Comment: Dunno how this is supposed to help. Enclosing `require_once()` into its own PHP tags is valid. So is the closing PHP tag at the end. I don't see how this is supposed to solve the problem, especially if it runs on his local machine

Comment: @YUNOWORK Because some servers will run the header redirect (Apache on Mac OS X I have found will ignore the whitespace), however most will not if there is output before the header, and there is a ton of blank output.

Comment: But it is safe, if OP has space after `?>`. this can be also responsible for header already sent error.

Comment: @Rasclatt Aaaah, ofc, the 2 lines between the first PHP tags ... I completely missed that. That's most likely the error, you're right.

Comment: The header is all the way down the page.

Comment: wow!! I could not believe that this solution works! but, it did! Thanks a lot @Viral.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening and closing the php tags each time on single php file.
just remove the closing tag form first line as:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/db.php');
```

and also remove the `<?php` tag from second line.

Answer (score 0):

Change the header look like this will work. Or

```
header('Location: index.htm');
```

Or

HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself:

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```